# What does the period indicate when an environmental variable is set like "VARIABLE_NAME=."

Tags: scripting, environment-variables

What does the period indicate when an environmental variable is set like `VARIABLE_NAME=.`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's not shell syntax - there's nothing special about it.  That assignment is assigning the string `.` to the shell variable (or environment variable - it's impossible to tell without more context) named `VARIABLE_NAME`

Comment: The actual environment variable is for Open Scene Graph which I need to build as a dependency for Ossim: "OPENSCENEGRAPH_USE_CMAKE_DIR=." This is inside my build.sh for ossim.

Comment: I see - in that case, `.` is being used as the name of the current directory.  Just like every directory (except the root) has a `..` entry that points to its parent, it has a `.` entry that points to itself.  So this variable is telling the Open Scene Graph build script that the directory to look for the cmake files it needs is the directory it's being executed from.

Comment: @godlygeek: The root directory does have a `..` entry. Another way to look at it is that every directory has a `..` entry pointing to its parent -- and the root directory `/` is its own parent.

Comment: @KeithThompson I was ambiguous, I suppose: "every directory (except the root) has a `..` entry that points to its parent" is a true statement, but I didn't add that "the root has a `..` entry that points to itself since it has no parent".

Comment: I wasn't trying to imply that the root directory didn't have a `..` entry at all, merely that it doesn't have a `..` directory pointing to its parent, since it doesn't have a parent.